# Showing Pdf files from a specific folder, into a fragment

Tags: java, android, pdf, mediastore, android-external-storage

I am trying to build a Pdf Scanner Android application for api level 21 and above, in the app I have an option to show and manage all the pdf files created by the application through the application.
I want to fetch Pdf files from Documents/PDFScanner folder and show them in a fragment. So far I am getting empty array but I have Pdf files in the folder.
I have tested the code on Android 11 and Android 8.1 devices.
here is my function to get pdf files

```
private void getPDFFilesFromDirecotry() {
    Uri collection = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    } else {
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    }

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor mediaCursor = applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(collection,
            projection,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " LIKE?",
            new String[]{Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/PDFScanner"},
            null);

    Log.e("TAG", "Message: " + mediaCursor.getCount());
    if (mediaCursor == null || mediaCursor.getCount() <= 0 || !mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e("tag","No data");
        return;
    }
    String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationContext, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{mimetype}, null);

    while (mediaCursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Message: ");
        String path = mediaCursor.getString(mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.e("TAG", "getPDFFilesFromDirectory Path: " + path);
        if (path != null) {
            ivNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            file = new File(path);

            String name = file.getName();
            int position = name.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (position > 0 && position < name.length() - 1) {
                name = name.substring(0, position);
            }
            Date dateinMillis = new Date(file.lastModified());
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm a");
            String date = dateFormat.format(dateinMillis);
            String size = formatSize(file.length());

            viewFilesArray.add(new ViewFilesModel(path, name, size, date));
        }
    }
    mediaCursor.close();

    Log.e("TAG", "getPDFFilesFromDirectory: " + viewFilesArray.size());
    filesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For Q+ use .RELATIVE_PATH instead of .DATA.

Comment: @blackapps  I tried that and it is not showing any documents in both Android 11 and lower versions

Comment: Show your adapted code. Those documents are created by your app?

Comment: Please start with what you do (app for android) and specify how you test it / on which (virtual) device and for which android version you develop. Thank you.